# Django Quiz Application Storing User responses

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a Django quiz application where there will be monthly quizzes. So suppose there will be a quiz for July and there will be a quiz for august. Now let's assume that we have a user who is named  "Sovit". Now let's say each quiz has 42 questions. so I want to store each response that the user has chosen somewhere in the database. So like For the July test all 42 responses must be stored somewhere and the same again for august. Right Now I am thinking of having a JSON file associated with the user and then storing the responses of each quiz inside that. What it will help me do is get the data in JSON format for data analysis purposes . But I am not really liking this method of storing the responses. What could be wrong with this design? Is there any other method that I can try?

current models :

```
class Quiz(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.quiz_name+"-"+str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.year)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.quiz_name:
            self.quiz_name = self.quiz_name+"-"+str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.year)
        super(Quiz,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    
class Question(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question+"-"+str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.year)


    

class Answers(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer


class UserQuizAnswer(models.Model):
    options = (
        (0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    selcted_index = models.IntegerField(choices=options)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + "-" + str(uuid.uuid4())[:10]


class StudentFile(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_netid = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    student_email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="Student/Files/",null=True,blank=True)
    month = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not need fields month and year in Question model (you already store this info in quiz models).
I think u forget link Answers to Question models.

To UserQuizAnswer you can use a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) to store the packaged data